# Gettin line number of the called function

Tags: c++, solaris

Please let me know if I can do it or not?

I am writing a library that could work to track memory allocation and de-allocation in C++. In short, I am trying to see if my application does not have any memory leaks. This is what I did so far.

Overrode the new and the delete operator and now. Whenever the application uses new, I am planning to store the address and the number of bytes that are allocated in that call. Similarly, when the delete is called on that address, I will remove that from the stored list. Until now its fine. But I want to store the file name and the line number from where the "new" is called. I can do that only in the overridden new. Is there a way to get line number in the overridden function?

---

```
1    int main()
2    {
3       // Say, A is a structure
4        A *a = new A();
5        return 0;
6     }
7    void* operator new( size )
8    {
9        //
10       // store the line number and file name on line 4 ??? Can I do it?
11       return (malloc(size));
12   }
------------------------
```

Comment: Why not use Valgrind? And not re-implement the wheel? Unless of course you really want to do this, of course

Comment: @Yuppie Valgrind isn't on Solaris.

Comment: For production-level testing on Solaris, use DTrace rather than writing your own profiler.

Comment: I've never used Valgrind but dTrace is my second option after I am sure that I cannot implement the way I described as above.

Comment: If you can afford it Purify will save you lots of headaches. Alternatively, if you can find it, there is a very small leak checking tool called `efence` I think the sources are available and you may be able to get this to work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++20 you can use [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)
which offers:

- line
- column
- file_name
- function_name

For previous versions of C++, traditionnally the macros `__LINE__` gives the line number but also `__FUNCTION__` and `__FILE__` are really helpful, giving the const char* of the enclosing function, and file name.

Indeedn, `__FUNCTION__` is not standard but supported by several compilers.

Unfortunately these macros only take their value in place.
So it is not possible for you to ask for the caller.

You should write the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros everywhere you use `new`. :(.

Comment: `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are standard C macros, and are not Visual Studio-specific. `__FUNCTION__` is not standard, but many compilers have equivalent alternatives.

Comment: yes... __LINE__ and __FILE__ are useful but like u said, they can be useful only when we use them in a macro. I do have a lot of news and dels in my many many processes in the application. So, thats a big headache... looks like the last resort, dTrace.

Comment: I don't know dTrace, I will have a look at it, nice to know.

Comment: DTrace is available on Solaris, OpenSolaris, MacOS X and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got an answer by one of similar threads in this forum... The following code worked... Lets say,

```
class A
{
    public:
    char str[1000];
    A()
    {
        strcpy(str,"Default string");
    }
    A(const char* s)
    {
        strcpy(str,s);
    }
};

void * operator new (unsigned size, char const * file, int line)
{
    cout << "File = " << file << endl;
    cout << "Line = " << line << endl;
    return( malloc(size));
}
#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
int main()
{
    A *a = new A("Leak");
    printf("%s",a->str);
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Related post where I found the answer...
[overloading new and delete in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509214/overloading-new-and-delete-in-c)

Comment: Please consider overloading operator delete, and operator new[], operator delete[], as per http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/010.htm .

Comment: What complier were you using? This does not work in g++ version 4.8.1

Comment: I'm not sure, whether such `#define` is standard compliant. For example, redefining `return` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the studio dbx run time checking feature to identify memory leaks under Solaris ( http://blogs.oracle.com/janitor/entry/runtime_memory_checking .) libumem can also be very helpful ( http://blogs.oracle.com/pnayak/entry/finding_memory_leaks_within_solaris .)