# c++ a function that returns its line number

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gettin line number of the called function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452557/gettin-line-number-of-the-called-function)

I'm debugging, and it's extremely useful for me to find a function that returns the position of this function in the code. More precisely, is there a function that can return the line number of the function in the code? For example, if I call f() in line x, the returned value is an integer x.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: What kind of construct are we talking about?

Comment: what? are you referring to a 2D array

Comment: show some code. this question is nonsensical for lack of context

Comment: just call `std::usher()` and it will tell you which row to use.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the `__LINE__` macro?
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: There should be a badge for editing a closed question with -5 and getting it back to 0 and reopened.

Comment: There should be a badge for editing a closed question with -5 and getting it back to 0 and reopened, which is soon after closed again.

Comment: Except it *is* a dupe. Anyway, the solution is to use a platform-specific stack backtrace. There is no way to do it semantically. Well, except by adding a `line_number` argument to `f()`, defining `#define F_MACRO(fn, ...) fn( VA_ARGS, __LINE__ )`, and always calling the macro… and the macro is specific to non-nullary functions…